# Разница между true/false против checked

Tags: jquery, javascript

У меня дикое недовольство.

```
$(":checkbox").prop('checked','checked');

$(":checkbox").prop('checked','true');
```

Вот какая между ними разница? Как лучше писать? НЕужели нельзя сделать единый стандарт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так думаю, что в первом случае да `'checked'`, но во втором все таки `true` без ковычек.
Исходя из обратной ситуации:

```
    typeof $(':checkbox:eq(0)').prop('checked'); //boolean
```

наверняка вариант с использованием `true, false` будет правильней.
А на счет стандартизации - язык развивается, дойдут и до этого руки

Comment: Очень крутой ответ.Благодарен

Answer (score 1):

Для jquery всё равно, что Вы будете писать checked или true. Он в любом случае установит валидное свойство.